# Having problems with Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-api, keytool

I am trying to setup a basic Google Maps application for Android 2.3.3. I tried developing in Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA just to name it. After failing too many times I am back to basic. Please help me with my API v1.

Currently my maps shows blank (emulator and my real device). This is my code (I tried every possible permission tag by the way):

I am signing the application with the default debug key and even when I sign it in release I still get the blank map.

All I want is to see a real map. 
(By the way I am not sure if the format of the text here is right so in a nutshell I just copied the code 1-1 from here [mapview v1 sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview))

The manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.hellogooglemaps"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

The activity layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="BLA_BLA_BLA_GOT_A_KEY"
/>
```

The activity

```
    package com.example.hellogooglemaps;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

    public class MyActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MD5 for default.keystore.

Then go to Windows>show view>other>Emulator control
and send the click the send button from Emulator control(C ordinates in Decimal)

Then again run your application Map should appear with some default US location.

For getting Map in Device you need to create MD5 from your Application keystore not the default keystore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine for Google Map API V1. So there must be some problem with your key. for what I know if it's a new generated key then Google doesn't provide keys for Google Map API V1, so it must be a key for Google Map API V2 and that's the reason it doesn't work.

Please try map V2,
Use the correct map key after generating, along with the below considerations:

> 1. Internet permission. 2 . Turn on Google map for Android V2 in the developer console. 3 . Use appropriate tags in manifest, for example
>      below:

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="xxx"/>

        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    </application>
```